# Equivalent of theano.tensor.switch in Tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, theano

Is there any function in Tensorflow which does the exact same thing as `theano.tensor.switch(cond, ift, iff)`?

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow you can use `tf.cond`(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond). There are some examples in the documentation.

Edit: As you mentioned, this operation is not element wise, then it's equivalent is tf.where (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where)

Comment: The problem is that it is not element wise.

Comment: Then for element wise conditions you should use tf.where